# General relativity: all masses are moving?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

My understanding is that what we call gravity is masses moving along paths in curved space -- it is not that gravity causes masses to move but they are ***already*** moving.

Why are they already moving? And is the speed of this motion the same for every mass, but only greater curvature seems to make them move faster near more massive attracting objects like planets?

Maybe this is more for HSM, but what led Einstein to assume every mass is already in motion?

Comment: Moving with respect to what?

Comment: Voting to reopen. A perfectly clear question with a good answer below.

Comment: @gandalf61: Thanks but massively downvoted. Honest question that I am sure many non-physicists wonder about as I do.

Answer (score 3):

Gravity is due to the bending of *spacetime* not just space, and the paths followed by objects are paths in spacetime. Even a "stationary" mass is moving forward in the time direction.

Comment: Maybe we should not use the word “moving“ in this context. See video [A new way to visualize gravity](https://youtu.be/wrwgIjBUYVc?feature=shared&t=464).

Answer (score 1):

One of the lessons of SR is that there is no such thing as "at rest", which means there is no such thing as "moving". For example, your twin in a rocket ship racing at 0.99 c to Rigel Kentaurus is perfectly "at rest" in his frame--which means his spacetime metric is diag$(1,-1,-1,-1)$, just like yours.

GR generalizes this to coordinate diffeomorphism invariance, meaning (at least) any inertial object can consider itself at rest, and all the physics works.

For example: one reason, before Copernicus, it was accepted that the Earth was stationary and the heavenly bodies moved around us is...according to general relativity: the earth is stationary and the heavenly bodies move around it is a perfectly valid choice of coordinates. It was all much-ado-about-coordiantes, and as we know: physics doesn't care about your choice coordinates.